# HttpClient Large String response Too Slowly

Tags: java

I'm working to get Large String of data from HTTP API, The problem is when the compiler run this line

```
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

It will take around 15-20 seconds to load the data because I have big string, and I tried to use another library for HTTP requests (OKHttp 3.0), but it's the same.

**The size of data around 11,000 records from DB**

How can I solve this problem and can load the data in a few seconds?!

Comment: How large are the individual records from the db ? What else do you do with that response ? Have you tried profiling / debugging your code and seeing what takes the most time ? Also: the compiler does _not_ run your code or load this data.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think the compiler needs 15-20 seconds, its just the execution time that may take so long.
2. Since this is about net-io, it could be a limitation on your interface?
3. Maybe increase the memory for the jvm if the string is really large.
4. There may be a performance issue in your EntiieUtils class